# Enchant doesn't seem to be reading `enchant.ordering`

Tags: emacs, aspell, enchant

I have installed `enchant` on my macbook. I would like to only use `AppleSpell` for all languages and have therefore created the file `~/.config/enchant/enchant.ordering` which looks like this ->

```
> cat ~/.config/enchant/enchant.ordering 
*:AppleSpell
```

Yet running `enchant-lsmod-2` shows that `aspell` is still selected and has precedence over `AppleSpell` ->

```
> enchant-lsmod-2
aspell (Aspell Provider)
AppleSpell (AppleSpell Provider)
```

What gives? How do I get `enchant` to read the config file such that it defaults to `AppleSpell` on mac?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue on OSX. I also tried adding `hunspell` to `enchant.ordering`, but `enchant-lsmod-2` is still only reporting:

```bash
$ enchant-lsmod-2
aspell (Aspell Provider)
AppleSpell (AppleSpell Provider)
```

I did, however, find OP's issue in enchant's github repo. Since I also wanted to add `nb_NO` the solution provided there was directly applicable.
[github issue](https://github.com/AbiWord/enchant/issues/328)

To break it down, here's what I did:

1. Navigate to the enchant install directory and edit the `AppleSpell.config` file.

   - For me it was located at `/usr/local/Cellar/enchant/2.5.0/share/enchant/AppleSpell.config`
2. Append `nb_NO  no    Norsk Bokmål` to the file.
3. Great success, I can now spell check my Norwegian.

However, I have not been able to get it to acknowledge `hunspell` at all on OSX.